# Can you get a class name as a constant for scala annotations?

Tags: scala, annotations

I have an [annotation](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html#dataType()) which requires a String describing a class name, eg `com.package.MyClass`.

I can pass it as a string but would like it to reference the class itself for compilation/refactoring.

However I cannot use `MyClass.getName.` or `classOf[MyClass].toString` because it is not a constant:

`Compilation error[annotation argument needs to be a constant`

Is there a way to get a const reference to a classes name? Or another way to reference the class names as a string in annotations?

Comment: Can you share how do you use that annotation?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik My use-case is adding swagger docs to a play webapp, eg https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/playing-with-swagger-using-swagger-and-swagger-ui/ . In my case I create the annotation using `@ApiImplicitParams(Array[ApiImplicitParam](
    new ApiImplicitParam(
      name="Something",
      dataType= "com.package.MyClass")
  ))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `classOf` because it runs on runtime and Java annotations requires constants as arguments. Instead, you could capture the name of your class during compile time using macros.

I would recommend you to use some library which can do that, for example [NameOf](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof).

Add dependency on your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.dwickern" %% "scala-nameof" % "1.0.3" % "provided"
```

Then you can use it like:

```
import com.github.dwickern.macros.NameOf._

@ApiImplicitParams(Array[ApiImplicitParam](
   new ApiImplicitParam(
     name="Something",
     dataType= qualifiedNameOfType[com.package.MyClass])
   )
)
```